# How to retrieve the top-5 largest values (integers) from a dictionary of key-value pairs?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, max, key-value

I have created 3 dictionaries from a function that iterates through a dataframe of the popular ios apps. The 3 dictionaries contain key-value pairs based on how often the key occur in the dataframe. From these dictionaries, I want to retrieve the 5 largest values of each dictionary as well as the corresponding keys. These are the results from the dataframe iterations. Obviously I can see this manually but I want python to determine the 5 largest.

```
Prices: {0.0: 415, 4.99: 10, 2.99: 13, 0.99: 31, 1.99: 13, 9.99: 1, 3.99: 2, 6.99: 3}
Genres: {'Productivity': 9, 'Shopping': 12, 'Reference': 3, 'Finance': 6, 'Music': 19, 'Games': 308, 'Travel': 6, 'Sports': 7, 'Health & Fitness': 8, 'Food & Drink': 4, 'Entertainment': 19, 'Photo & Video': 25, 'Social Networking': 21, 'Business': 4, 'Lifestyle': 4, 'Weather': 8, 'Navigation': 2, 'Book': 4, 'News': 2, 'Utilities': 12, 'Education': 5}
Content Ratings: {'4+': 304, '12+': 100, '9+': 54, '17+': 30}
```

Comment: I’m curious, do you mind sharing the code that creates these dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the dictionaries by values and then slice the top 5:

```
sorted(Prices, key=Prices.get, reverse=True)[:5]
```

Same for the other two dicts.

Answer (score 0):

you can also accomplish this using itemgetter.

```
prices= {0.0: 415, 4.99: 10, 2.99: 13, 0.99: 31, 1.99: 13, 9.99: 1, 3.99: 2, 6.99: 3}
genres= {'Productivity': 9, 'Shopping': 12, 'Reference': 3, 'Finance': 6, 'Music': 19, 'Games': 308, 'Travel': 6, 'Sports': 7, 'Health & Fitness': 8, 'Food & Drink': 4, 'Entertainment': 19, 'Photo & Video': 25, 'Social Networking': 21, 'Business': 4, 'Lifestyle': 4, 'Weather': 8, 'Navigation': 2, 'Book': 4, 'News': 2, 'Utilities': 12, 'Education': 5}
contentRatings= {'4+': 304, '12+': 100, '9+': 54, '17+': 30}

arr = [prices,contentRatings,genres]

from operator import itemgetter 


for test_dict in arr:
  # printing original dictionary 
  print("The original dictionary is : " + str(test_dict)) 

  # 5 largest values in dictionary 
  # Using sorted() + itemgetter() + items() 
  res = dict(sorted(test_dict.items(), key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True)[:5]) 

  # printing result 
  print("The top 5 value pairs are  " + str(res))
```